# Getting error while Generating Thumbnail of Image in aws s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

when i upload image to direct Backet it work fine but in case of folder getting error to

Line=> s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)

download_path.

```
for record in event['Records']:
    
            bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
            key = record['s3']['object']['key']
    
            download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
    
            upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)
    
            print('Bucket Path', bucket)
            print('Key path', key)
            print('Download path', download_path)
            print('Upload path', upload_path)
    
            s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
            resize_image(download_path, upload_path)
            s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '{}-resized'.format(bucket), key)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: [ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/398cc938-76bd-4bef-b0e0-85fa489858f3images/512/cb301428-a5cb-411d-a641-afdf91807daf6th.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that you are using code from [Sample Amazon S3 function code - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python).

That code has an additional line that removes slashes:

```py
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])
        tmpkey = key.replace('/', '')                         # <--- This line here!
        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), tmpkey)  # <--- Used here
        upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(tmpkey)
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        resize_image(download_path, upload_path)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '{}-resized'.format(bucket), key)
```

This allows Python to store the file without having to create the hierarchical directories.